# NotificationPreferenceFragment - default constructor is deprecated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

My code is:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
        Preference notificationPref = findPreference("notifications_new_message");
        notificationPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener((preference, newValue) -> {
            boolean isNotificationOn = (Boolean) newValue;
            if(preference.getKey().equals("notifications_new_message") && isNotificationOn){
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
            }else{
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news");
            }
            return true;
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityPref.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Android Studio report that default constructor of NotificationPreferenceFragment is deprecated. How to fix deprecated warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AndroidX Preference Library. This library manages the user interface and interacts with storage so that you define only the individual settings that the user can configure.

```
public class MySettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
 @Override
 public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
 }
}
```

For more detail: Follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Comment: All look great except …. if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) { … where I get error "error: incompatible types: Preference cannot be converted to RingtonePreference"

Comment: wasn't implemented for androidx yet.